# how to import .dmp(Oracle-64bit-HPUX) on Oracle 64bit Windows..?

Tags: import, oracle10g

we have a .dmp file which was exported from the Oracle 10.2, 64 bit, HPUX OS database.
can we import this .dmp file into an Oracle 10.2, 64 bit but Windows(instead of HPUX) database...
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can import the .dmp on a different platform.

It would be helpful to know how the .dmp file was created (the options used for the `exp` program). The .dmp file could contain just data, or schema information and data of a single user or a full database. Depending on that, there are different options required to import it.

If your Oracle database on Windows is basically empty, you can try a full import first. If it doesn't work, you can derive from the error messages what's missing (e.g. schema information).

To import the schema file, use the `imp` program that comes with every Oracle installation.